# PHP - How to check if variable matches database entry?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in a database with a section called custom field type. If this matches as "textfield" i want to echo a textfield, if it matches "textarea" i want to echo a text area.

Can somebody let me know what I'm doing wrong below please?

```
    <?php if($this->item->custom_field_type1 == 'textfield') {
       echo 'this is a text field';
   }
   ?>
```

Comment: check if($this->item->custom_field_type1 == 'text')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution might help you

```
<?php if($this->item->custom_field_type1 == 'textfield') {
       echo '<input type="text">';
   }
if($this->item->custom_field_type1 == 'textarea') {
       echo '<textarea></textarea>';
   }
   ?>
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried something similar, and then your exact code above, but it still doesn't seem to work. I know it can see the database because all the other fields are working.

Comment: what is returning in `$this->item->custom_field_type1`

Comment: Sorry I think I found the problem somewhere else, something to do with the joomla compononent files that I am trying to build. Thanks for your help, I tested it else where and that code was all great.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo ($this->item->custom_field_type1 == 'textfield'?'<input type="text" />':'<textarea></textarea>'); ?>
```